# Multi Region/Location Use Case on EC2

Tags: arcgis-server, amazon-ec2

Context: ArcGIS applications for one of our customers are currently running on multiple sites in Americas, Europe, Australia and Africa geos (15 different countries). They are considering a cloud model. As you all are aware AWS provides 5 regions and support few edge locations for each of the regions.

Challenge: The coverage is not adequate for the current scenario. Considering that the applications are currently hosted at 15 different locations. Running intensive analysis on a ArcGIS cloud based solution results into a substandard user experience is my understanding.

Question: My question to the experts on this forum is cloud a suitable model to be recommended for my client. I have read about caching and elastic caching but are they really going to be effective considering the geo spread. My major concern is around latency with EC2s limited coverage and hence user experience will be taking a big hit.

Case Studies: I am keen to hear about case studies of similar nature use cases if any.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Sameer